# varying depth nested dict from list of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

## Problem statement

I aim at remapping the keys (essentially by swapping them) of a nested dictionary with varying depth, by using a mapping list.

My approach is:

1. flatten the dictionary and turn it into a list of tuples,
2. rebuild the dictionary and swap the keys by using a mapping list.

I was able to do #1, I am looking for a fine solution for #2. Generally speaking, I would love the solution to be as general as possible.

## Specific case

I have a N to N-1 level nested dictionary, where the first three levels needs to be swapped given a mapping. A chunk of my dictionary looks like this:

```
raw_dict = {'a':{'b':{'c':[1,2,3]}},
            'd':{'e':{'f':{'g':[4,5,6]}}}}
```

I managed to flatten the raw dictionary to a list of tuples with recursion, i.e. with the following function

```py
def unnest(d, keys=[]):
    '''
    convert a dictionary to a (ordered) list of tuples
    input: dictionary
    output: list of tuples
    '''
    lt = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            lt.extend(unnest(v, keys + [k]))
        else:
            lt.append(tuple(keys + [k, v]))
    return lt
```

Now, I have a list of tuples with varying length, but the longest element is always 1 element longer than the shortest (basically every tuple has either N or N-1 elements). Given `raw_dict` from the example above, the resulting list of tuples would be like this

`reform_list = [('a','b','c',[1,2,3]),('d','e','f','g',[4,5,6])]`

where the first has length 4 (N-1) and the second has length 5 (N).

## What I would like to achieve...

...is to build a function that builds a nested dictionary based on the tuple, regardless of the length, but based on a mapping like the following:

`my_map = [2,1,0,3]`

The function would be something like

```py
def nest(my_tuple,my_map):
    [do something]
    return my_dict
```

I would call the function in a loop like this

```py
for t in reform_list:
    n_d = nest(t,my_map)
    print(n_d)
```

The expected outcome of the loop would be:

```
{'c':{'b':{'a':[1,2,3]}}}
{'f':{'e':{'d':{'g':[4,5,6]}}}}
```

## In the last step...

...I will build the swapped dictionary by updating it, regardless of the depth, with recursion, starting from the single ones generated in the "wanted" function by using the following function

```py
def update(d, u):
    '''
    update nested dictionary
    input: dict to update (d), update to use (u)
    output: updated dict (d)
    '''
    for k, v in u.items():
        if isinstance(v, collections.abc.Mapping):
            d[k] = update(d.get(k, {}), v)
        else:
            d[k] = v
    return d
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: So you need help with creating a function that permutes a tuple based on `my_map`? Is it guaranteed that `my_map[-1] == len(my_map)-1`?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I thaught the answer was stated clearly, but I can edit my question to be clearer. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @a_guest yes, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
reform_list = [('a','b','c',[1,2,3]),('d','e','f','g',[4,5,6])]
my_map = [2,1,0,3] 
def build_dict(mp, val):
  if not mp or len(val) - 1 <= mp[0]:
     return val[-1]
  return {val[mp[0]]:build_dict(mp[1:],val)}

results = [build_dict(my_map, i) for i in reform_list]
```

Output:

```
[{'c': {'b': {'a': [1, 2, 3]}}}, {'f': {'e': {'d': {'g': [4, 5, 6]}}}}]
```

Comment: I mark this as the correct answer, because it does exactly what I was asking.
I wonder if there is a way to use this function to update the dictionary, so if the keys (regardless the level) are the same, the dict gets updated as in the `update` function I posted above.